# What is the probability that your pin has exactly one pair of digits the same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From the solution I get the sample space to be $|\Omega| = 9 \times 10^3$. This suggests that a a pin number can not start with a $0$, and it is $4$ digits long. As for the rest of the solution I can not understand where the logic is coming from:

$$|A| = 9 \times 8 \times 3 +  9 \times 8 \times 3 \times 3 + 9 \times {8 \choose2}4!/2!.$$

And the probability is given by $\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$. I would like to understand how this is derived.

My attempt went long the lines of saying that there are $4 \choose 2$ ways of choosing the locations of the repeated number. The remaining can be chosen in $4 \choose 2$ ways. But this does not resemble the answer in any way.

I would like to understand the derivation of the answer given.

Comment: I can give the start of a possible derivation. The digit $0$ has to be treated specially. The first term, $9 \times 8 \times 3 $ gives the number of pin numbers which have exactly one pair of zeroes, 3 being the number of possible positions for the pair and $9 \times 8$ being the choices for the other two digits. You have to add to this the number of pins with exactly one pair of non-zero digits. The rest of the sum, I think divides these into 2 groups: one where the first digit is one of the pair, and the other where neither of the pair is the first digit. However I have not thought this out.

Comment: "My attempt went long the lines of saying that there are $4 \choose 2$ ways of choosing the locations of the repeated number." : Per the comment of @MichaelCohen, this is **wrong**.  If the repeated **digit** is $(0)$, then there are only $$\binom{3}{2}$$ possible locations of the repeated digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user2661923 has provided you with a nice approach using complementary counting and an elegant approach using symmetry.

**An explanation of the stated solution**

The author of the stated solution considers three cases:

- zero is the repeated digit
- zero is not the repeated digit, but it appears once
- zero does not appear

*Zero is the repeated digit*:  There are nine ways to select the leading digit, eight ways to select the other nonzero digit, and three ways to place that nonzero digit among the last three positions.  Thus, there are $$9 \cdot 8 \cdot 3$$ such PINs.

*Zero is not the repeated digit*:  There are nine ways to select the nonzero digit that appears twice, eight ways to pick the other nonzero digit, three ways to pick the location of the zero (since it cannot appear in the first position), and three ways to pick the position of the other digit that appears once.  Hence, there are $$9 \cdot 8 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$$ such PINs.

*Zero does not appear*:  There are nine ways to pick the nonzero digit that appears twice, $\binom{8}{2}$ ways to pick the two digits that each appear once, and $\frac{4!}{2}$ ways to arrange the four selected digits since interchanging the two identical digits does not change the PIN. Hence, there are $$9\binom{8}{2} \cdot \frac{4!}{2}$$ such PINs.

*Total*:  Since the three cases above are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of favorable cases is indeed
$$9 \dot 8 \cdot 3 + 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 + 9\binom{8}{2} \cdot \frac{4!}{2}$$

**The approach Michael Cohen suggested in the comments**

We again consider three cases:

zero is the repeated digit

a nonzero digit is repeated and appears in the first position

a nonzero digit is repeated and does not appear in the first position

*Zero is the repeated digit*:  Since zero cannot appear in the leading position, there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to select the positions of the two zeros, nine ways to select the leading digit, and eight ways to select the remaining digit.  Hence, there are $$\binom{3}{2} \cdot 9 \cdot 8$$ such PINs.

*A nonzero digit is the repeated digit and appears in the first position*:  There are nine ways to select the leading digit, three ways to choose the other position of the leading digit, $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to select the two digits which will each appear once, and $2!$ ways to arrange those two distinct digits in the remaining two positions.  There are $$9 \cdot 3 \binom{9}{2}2!$$ such PINs.

*A nonzero digit is the repeated digit and does not appear in the first position*:  There are nine ways to select the digit which appears twice, $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to place it in two of the last three positions, eight ways to select a nonzero leading digit from among the remaining nonzero digits, and eight ways to select the digit which will appear in the remaining open position.  Hence, there are $$9\binom{3}{2} \cdot 8 \cdot 8$$ such PINs.

*Total*:  Since the three cases listed above are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, there are
$$\binom{3}{2} \cdot 9 \cdot 8 + 9 \cdot 3 \binom{9}{2}2! + 9\binom{3}{2} \cdot 8 \cdot 8$$
favorable cases.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I also have trouble understanding the thinking behind the offered solution.  Regardless of whether the offered solution is accurate/valid, I feel that it is poorly communicated.

My approach would be to dispense with any attempt at elegance, and break the problem down as follows:

You are given that the sample space is $9 \times 10^{3}$, so, as the OP (i.e. original poster) inferred, the sample space is any four digit number whose left-most digit is not equal to $(0)$.

---

While I believe in forgoing elegance, I also believe in trying to make my life easier.  My approach would be to pretend that the left-most digit can be $(0)$, enumerate the number of satisfying four digit numbers, under that pretense, and then deduct the number of (otherwise) satisfying four digit numbers whose left most digit is $(0)$.

---

Ignoring the constraint about the left most digit, there are $(10)$ choices for the repeating digit.  Then, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ choices for the placement of the repeating digit.  Then, there are $(9 \times 8)$ choices for the remaining two digits, where-ever these digits happen to be placed.

So, I would start with the initial (pretense) enumeration of

$$A = 10 \times \binom{4}{2} \times (9 \times 8) = 4320.$$

---

I will let $B$ denote the portion of the enumeration of $A$ that has a leftmost digit of $(0)$.  Then, the final enumeration of the **numerator** will be

$$A - B.$$

---

To enumerate $B$, first you assume that the left-most digit is $(0)$.  Then, you have two cases to consider: either the repeated digit is $(0)$ specifically, or it is not.  I will represent these two enumerations as $B_1, B_2$, so that

$$B = B_1 + B_2.$$

For $B_1$, there are $(3)$ locations for the second $(0)$.  Then, there are $(9 \times 8)$ ways of completing the number.

Therefore,

$$B_1 = 3 \times 9 \times 8 = 216.$$

For $B_2$, there are $9$ choices for which digit (other than $0$) will be the repeated digit.  Further, since it is being assumed that the leftmost digit is $(0)$, there are only $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{2}~$ choices for where the repeated digit will be placed.  Then, there will be $(8)$ choices for the digit to be used in the 4th position.

So,

$$B_2 = 9 \times 3 \times 8 = 216.$$

Therefore,

$$B = B_1 + B_2 = 216 + 216 = 432.$$

Therefore, the **numerator** of the probability problem is

$$A - B = 4320 - 432 = 3888.$$

---

Now, having *eschewed* elegance, I can re-embrace it.  If you examine the enumeration of $A = 4320$, by reasons of **symmetry**, you would expect that any given element in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}$ is just as *likely* as any other given element to be the leftmost digit.

Therefore, it *makes sense* that the final computation of the numerator is

$$\frac{9}{10} \times A = \frac{9}{10} \times 4320.$$